# Not able to use \MakeLowercase in a subsection

Tags: formatting

I am trying to make some of the words in my subsections lowercase, but for example using `\subsection{Goals \MakeLowercase{and} Impact}` just leads to the following error: `"Argument of \MakeLowercase has an extra }."`

I am however able to make a word lowercase as long as it's not already within `{}`, so just writing `\MakeLowercase{Hello}` works.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{NSF}

\begin{document}
\title{Project}

\subsection{Goals and Impact}
These are my goals and impact

\end{document}
```

What I am trying to do:

```
\documentclass{NSF}

\begin{document}
\title{Project}

\subsection{Goals \MakeLowercase{and} Impact}
These are my goals and impact

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SE. The code you posted works fine for me… Are you sure of the pasted code? Have you tried and searched your code for unmatched parenthesis?

Comment: That's the exact code I'm using, could the document class have anything to do with this? I'm using NSF.

Comment: TBH, I don't know, but it's always best to include a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), perhaps at the end of your post. Maybe there's something you missed or some weird interaction

Comment: Please, add a pointer to the class file